# Can't get lightning to work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning three.js and I got in this problem. I made a cube that I can spin with A and D buttons. But I can't get the lightning to work. I looked up a few examples and just copied them, but they still don't work. Am I missing something obvious?

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
scene.add(camera);

//lightning
let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
let lightAmbient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
light.position.set(3, 0, 0).normalize();
scene.add(light, lightAmbient);

let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(800, 600);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x539cef});
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);
camera.position.z = 3;

let left = false;
let right = false;
cube.rotation.x += 0.5;

function animate() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if(event.keyCode === 65) {
            left = true;
        }
        if(event.keyCode === 68) {
            right = true;
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
        left = right = 0;
    })

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if(left) {
        cube.rotation.y -= 0.05;
    } else if(right) {
        cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to use `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()`, as they're affected by light, instead of `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add directional light to camera instead of scene and use `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` or `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()`.